# I am not able to align my html control to right in html table

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, html-table

My requirement is I want to align my radio button to left in table cell, but it is not happening with the below code:

My code

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Action</h3>
    <table class="tabledata" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="td1">
                <p>
                    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="Approve" /></p>
            </td>
            <td class="td2">Approve</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio2" type="radio" /></td>
            <td class="td2">Reject</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio3" type="radio" />
            </td>
            <td class="td2">Send Back to Requestor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount Approved for Domestic sector : </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Remarks : </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text2" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tabledata">
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My CSS classes:

```
.td1 {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
}

.td2 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Actually I want to keep my radio button and its corresponding text in a table row by combining 2 columns and centre aligned and also submit button shoud be centre aligned in a table row since I am using jquery mobile datarole I guess it is not happening.Please help me to get the look.

After adding the script in head also I am getting below output:

[image]

Comment: apart from the first one (which is right aligned due to `td1`, they are left aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/yHbdn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ui-radio` class from each radio button.

```
$('[type=radio]').each(function () {
 $(this).closest('div').removeClass('ui-radio');
});
```

and add class `td1` to each radio button.

```
<tr>
 <td class="td1">
  <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="Approve" />
 </td>
 <td class="td2">Approve</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="td1">
  <input id="Radio2" type="radio" />
 </td>
 <td class="td2">Reject</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="td1">
  <input id="Radio3" type="radio" />
 </td>
 <td class="td2">Send Back to Requestor</td>
</tr>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/63GyZ/)**

---

> **Alternative method:** No jQuery code is required nor custom CSS styles. Read more about it [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/radiobuttons).

Why don't you use styled radio buttons, as in the below demo.

**[Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vhwqw/)**

Comment: still not happening.. I have kept the script in head section of cshtml page.

Comment: put the script in body and try again. However, I highly recommend using the alternative method. @user1912987

Comment: I dont want styled radio buttons and my radio buttons should be center aligned instead of left aligned..

Comment: See I have attached my output..I am getting lot of space between radio button and text that's is the reason i have aligned my radio button to right but for some reason it is not happening.. Sorry my radio button should be right aligned..

Comment: Ok, have you added your custom class `td1` to each `<td>` which contain your buttons? as per the demo in my answer?

Comment: Add this to the body `$(document).on('pageshow', function () { $('[type=radio]').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('ui-radio');
}); });`

Comment: @omar.. Thanks omar it is happening now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28508/discussion-between-user1912987-and-omar)

Comment: @Omar..But still look is not good...I want radio button and approve side by side and centre of table row...If i am not using table I am getting radio button and approve in different line since i am using collapsable div..Please give me some ideas it is not necessary that i need to use table control...Please check submit button also it should be aligned centre...

Comment: You can use grids http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids.html they are flexible and responsive. Read about and if you have any question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

new CSS:

```
tr td:nth-child(1) {
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHbdn/1/